# how to extract a numner after a sequence of words

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a number that follows a certain sequence of words (and there is a space after a number) the following way:

```
users_pattern = '\bnumber of users\s+(.*?)\s+\b'
users_pattern = re.compile(users_pattern)
n = users_pattern.match('... number of users 50,333 and updated information')
```

n, however, is none. Does anyone know how to adjust the regex pattern in order to extract the number after a sequence of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several issues:

- A word boundary is specified with a literal backslash and `b`, thus you either need `'\\b'` or `r'\b'`.
- The `re.match` only searches for a match at the start of string.
- If you happen to have a match at the end of string, your `\s+\b` pattern would not let it match. You need `\S+` pattern to capture all chars up to the first whitespace.

Thus, you can use

```py
import re
users_pattern = r'\bnumber of users\s+(\S+)'
users_pattern = re.compile(users_pattern)
n = users_pattern.search('... number of users 50,333 and updated information')
if n:
    print(n.group(1))

# => 50,333
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0e3hMM).

Note that the `n.group(1)` is only called after checking if `n` matched with `if` n`. Else, it could throw an exception upon no match.